# current r codes take longtime to extract climate data from worldlcim, how to make this faster

Tags: r, csv, gis, raster

Currently my code is taking too long to extract climate variables from the [worldclim][1] dataset. I would like to download the climate data from the link and find the maximum temperature over my species distribution polygons and save as a CSV file in a directory.

The code is working, but taking too long (say, 3-4 days on my PC). Can anybody suggest how to improve the performance of my code?

My code is here:

```
# download the climate dataset and unzip. I can download and unzip this into my pc. Please suggest me on main codes for improvement
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/cmip5/30s/mi85tx50.zip", destfile = "E://ClimateDataOutputs//MIROC-ESM-CHEM_rcp85TX", mode="wb")
unzip("E://ClimateDataOutputs//MIROC-ESM-CHEM_rcp85TX")
# Codes for improvement
# load required packages
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(lsr)
require(maptools)
# For Bioclim - Need to project species polygons
projection <- CRS ("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
polygons <- readShapePoly("F:\\9. Other projects\\All projected maps\\AllP.shp", proj4string = projection)
polygons$BINOMIAL <- as.character(polygons$BINOMIAL)
names=c(polygons$BINOMIAL)
stats_out<- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = 579))
colnames(stats_out)<-c("BINOMIAL", "AAD", "mean", "obs")
stats_out[,1]<-names
# iterate over species polygons


for (i in 1:579) {
    poly<-polygons[i,]
    print(poly$BINOMIAL)
    data_out<-data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 1))
    colnames(data_out)<-c("MaxTemp2050rcp85_MIROC_ESM_CHEM")` 



    for (j in 1:12) {
        filename<-c(paste("E:\\ClimateDataOutputs\\mi85tx50",j,".tif", sep=""))
        ##print(filename)
        grid<-raster(filename)
        ##plot(grid)
        ##plot(poly, add=TRUE)
        data<-extract(grid, poly)
        data1<-as.data.frame(data)
        colnames(data1)<-c("MaxTemp2050rcp85_MIROC_ESM_CHEM")
        data_out= rbind(data_out,data1)
        }



    M<-mean(data_out$MaxTemp2050rcp85_MIROC_ESM_CHEM, na.rm=TRUE)
    AAD<-aad(data_out$MaxTemp2050rcp85_MIROC_ESM_CHEM, na.rm=TRUE)
    stats_out$AAD[i]<-AAD
    stats_out$mean[i]<-M
    stats_out$obs[i]<-nrow(data_out)
  }


print(stats_out)
write.csv(stats_out, "E://ClimateDataOutputs//MaxTemp2050rcp85_MIROC_ESM_CHEM_AAD.csv")
```

Comment: you should reverse the 2 loops as reading a file is quite long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you stack your rasters?

```
stack(list.files("E:\\ClimateDataOutputs","mi85tx50",full.names=T))
data<-extract(grid, poly)
```

It may help

Other option, the line:

```
data_out= rbind(data_out,data1)
```

is very inefficient.  It's always better in a loop to prepare the object first and fill it up like `data_out[j,] <- data1`

Finally, it's a little harder, but find a way to make your "j" loop into a function and parallelize your analyses with `parLapply` on all of your polygons.

Also, it's always better with those kind of question to add the `system.time` statement so we know more where the bottleneck is.